# syntax highlighting for Assembler

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

I need to add support for assembler language I'm working with (it is not x86, 68K, or 8051 which are well supported by vim). I looked at the existing syntax files, and here are my questions

1) When does it really make sense to use `syn keyword` and `syn match`?  My understanding is that the latter supports regex and gives more flexibility. On the other way, looking at `/usr/share/vim/vim70/syntax/asmh8300.vim` - they define opcodes in both `keyword` and `match`, what benefit does it really give?

2) Instructions in my Asm have a common format:

`INSTR OP1, OP2 ..;`  i.e. space delimits the instruction name from operands.

I think for this I'm ok with only defining all Asm commands in 'keyword' since space symbol is by default in `'iskeyword'`. Am I right ?

3) The Asm also supports C-style structures, enums and comments. Can I just borrow its syntax definition from c.vim or it won't work and requires some tweaking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a limited set of identifiers, and if they all consist solely of *keyword characters*, then `:syn keyword` is the best choice. You're right in that `:syn match` provides a superset of functionality. Essentially,

```
:syn keyword myGroup foobar
```

is equivalent to

```
:syn match myGroup "\<foobar\>"
```

### Beware of old versions

The `syntax/asmh8300.vim` syntax you've referenced is from 2002, it may not be the best example of how to write a syntax file. (For example, it omits the `\<...\>` around its matches, what looks like a bug to me. And it still has compatibility stuff for Vim 5 / 6 that's not needed any more.)

Also, do you actually use Vim 7.0?! Vim 7.0 is from 2007 and *very* outdated. It should be possible to install the latest version 7.3; if you can't find a proper package for your distribution (for Windows, check the binaries from the [Cream project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cream/files/Vim/), it's also not very difficult to [compile](http://www.vim.org/download.php) (e.g. from the Mercurial sources) on Linux.

### Borrow other syntax elements

If other syntaxes are embedded in your syntax, and clearly delimited (e.g. like JavaScript inside HTML), you can `:syn include` it. But if there are just similar constructs, it's best to copy-and-paste them into your syntax (and adapt at least the group names). You need to be careful to catch all contained syntax groups, too; together with syntax clusters, the hierarchy can be quite complex!

### More tips

When writing a syntax, you often need to find out which syntax group causes the highlighting. `:syn list` shows all active groups, but it's easier when you install the [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin.